# Tool to remove image parts in PDF

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, pdf, high-sierra, software

The reader of my university lecture regularly posts lecture notes online. The pdf contains handwritten mathematical theorems including the proofs. Everything is written on a completely white background.

I want to create a new printable file containing the theorems and comments only (no proofs) as exam preparation

Is there an easy tool able to accomplish this on a Mac running High Sierra? It may be a bit tricky to get the breaks in pages right.  The workflow would ideally look like this:

Use rectangular selection tool to highlight proof. Hit some key to delete selected area/fill the rectangle white. Select *everything* below the proof and move it upwards until no whitespace is left.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe think from the opposite side...

- Open your PDF
- Select an area you want to *keep*.
- <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>C</kbd>  to copy, then  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>N</kbd>  which will open a new document with the clipboard contents.
- Repeat for each section you want to keep.
- Save each of your new sections as separate files. Use the default name, which will number in save order, these will be ephemeral.
- Close everything.
- Select all your newly-saved files in Finder & Open
- They will all open in one window, in file order.
- You can then Print the whole lot as a single document - to PDF.

Requires Preview prefs > General > Open groups of files in the same window

[image]

Comment: Saving works, but when selecting multiple files and opening them will lead to multiple preview windows. How do I merge these files?

Comment: Preview prefs > General > Open groups of files in same window

Comment: Strange. This is already selected. You just selected all the files in Finder - Open With - Preview?

Comment: Yup, or for me as Preview is default, just select, cmd/O

Comment: Still not doing it for me. Maybe I'm selecting wrong or something. Even selecting _Open all files in one window_ does not work.

Comment: It's doing as each pref says it should, for me

Comment: I can just open the first part and append the other parts via drag and drop. This will probably do it. I'm still a little bit bothered that all parts are now on a separate page. How do I control where a new page starts?

Comment: each will be a separate page, Cmd/1 for continuous scroll

Comment: Yes, but where will a new page start, when I try to print the pdf? Some theorems are only of one line height and currently occupy a whole page.

Comment: You didn't say you were actually going to print it. To concatenate to A4 printable pages you'll need 3rd party software.

Comment: Oh, sorry for the confusion. I'll edit my question to clarify.